# How to fix "You must feed a value for placeholder tensor" when dealing with GAN framework?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement a GAN with Keras (Tensorflow backend) to colorize an image. My generator has a gray-scale input image whereas my discriminator has both the gray-scale and the colored image as inputs.

How can I train my generator without having the error

> "InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor
>   'input_2' with dtype float and shape [?,128,128,1] [[{{node
>   input_2}}]] [[{{node metrics/acc/Mean_2}}]]"

I have tried different ways to create the combined model (used to train the generator) without success. I am using Python 3.6.7 and Keras 2.2.4.

```py
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, BatchNormalization, Activation, AveragePooling2D, Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Lambda, MaxPool2D, Conv2DTranspose, UpSampling2D, Concatenate, Add
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from keras.preprocessing import image

def combine_generator(gen1, gen2):
    while True:
        yield(gen1.next(), gen2.next())

def generator_model(input_img):   
    outputs = Conv2D(3, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid') (input_img)
    model = Model(inputs=[input_img], outputs=[outputs])
    return model

def discriminator_model(output_img, input_img):
    a1 = Concatenate()([output_img, input_img])
    f1 = Flatten()(a1)
    output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(f1)
    model = Model(inputs=[output_img, input_img], outputs=[output])
    return model

def generator_containing_discriminator(input_img, generator, discriminator):
    goutput = generator(input_img)
    discriminator.trainable=False
    doutput = discriminator([goutput, input_img])
    model = Model(inputs=[input_img], outputs=[doutput])
    return model

seed = 123456
input_size = 128
batch_size = 8
learning_rate = 1e-3
optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate)

dir_train_img = "flowers_train"
data_gen = dict(rescale=1./255)
image_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen)

color_generator_train = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(dir_train_img, batch_size=batch_size, class_mode=None, target_size=(input_size, input_size), color_mode="rgb", seed=seed)
gray_generator_train = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(dir_train_img, batch_size=batch_size, class_mode=None, target_size=(input_size, input_size), color_mode="grayscale", seed=seed)
train_generator = combine_generator(color_generator_train, gray_generator_train)

dmodel = discriminator_model(Input((input_size, input_size, 3)), Input((input_size, input_size, 1)))
dmodel.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
dmodel.summary()

gmodel = generator_model(Input((input_size, input_size, 1)))
gmodel.summary()

gdmodel = generator_containing_discriminator(Input((input_size, input_size, 1)), gmodel, dmodel)
gdmodel.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
gdmodel.summary()

dmodel.trainable=False

train_batch = next(train_generator)
labels2 = np.array([1]*len(train_batch[1]))
gdmodel.train_on_batch(train_batch[1], labels2)
```

As shown in the summary, the input_2 corresponds to the gray-scale input image of the discriminator, but I don't know where the problem comes from.

Answer (score 1):

The problem disappears when I remove the parameter metrics=["accuracy"] from the line:

```py
gdmodel.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

I don't know why though.

Comment: I had the same problem and when I removed the parameter you mentioned the error disappeared! I am very curious as to why this happens. Were you able to figure out why this happens?